# Sort data and update field to True

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooF1k.png)While sorting **json** by Group name, how to set IsMerged Json property to true?

SampleJson:

```
[{"SessionId":"s1",
  "SessionName":"Session Name 1",
  "StartDateTime":"2019-05-16T04:00:00",
  "Groups":[
    {"GroupID":"g1", 
     "GroupName":"Group Name1",
     "HideChildren":false,
     "IsMerged":false
    },
    {"GroupId":"g2",
     "GroupName":"Group Name2",
     "HideChildren":false,
     "IsMerged":false
    }
    //...
}]
```

Like above there are different sessions and groups(Nested JSON).
I am able to sort using $filter

Comment: what do you mean by _isMoved_ property

Comment: It is hard to help you with your sorting function when the question does not include its code.

Comment: More details will help

Comment: I have a nested Json, on a button click i would like to sort the data by Group Name and want to set IsMerged Property to True to track what and all Groupnames were rearranged.

Comment: Added more details and two images. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Let groupNameSelected ='Group Name2'

let q = p[0]['Groups'];

q.map((obj)=>{
  return groupNameSelected === obj.GroupName ? {...obj, IsMerged:true } : obj;
});
```

Based on the group name selected, you would run map on `Groups` and then it would set the values of the `IsMerged` to true.

final Output for `Group Name2` selection would be:

```
[ { GroupID: 'g1',
    GroupName: 'Group Name1',
    HideChildren: false,
    IsMerged: false },
  { GroupId: 'g2',
    GroupName: 'Group Name2',
    HideChildren: false,
    IsMerged: true } 
     //...
    ]
```